# Set Twig layout in controller

Tags: symfony, twig

I have multiple subdomains, each with its own layout. Some controllers are shared across subdomains (e.g login), some not. What I'd like to do is to set layout according to domain, so that I would not need to write in each template:

```
{% if app.request.domain == 'one' %}
  {% set layout = '::layout-one.html.twig' %}
{% elseif app.request.domain == 'two' %}
  {% set layout = '::layout-two.html.twig' %}
...
{% endif %}
{% extends layout %}
```

Is it possible to set default layout in controller (or somewhere)? E.g:

```
class FooController 
{
    function fooAction()
    {
        ...
        $templating = $this->get('templating');
        $templating->setLayout($layout);
        return $templating->renderResponse($view, $parameters, $response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `layout` variable in your `FooController`:

```
class FooController 
{
    function fooAction()
    {
        ...
        return $this->render($template, array(
            'layout' => $layout
        ));
    }
}
```

And then use it in your template:

```
{% extends layout %}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a separate config file for each of the domains, you can put the layout config in there and have it available in twig as a global variable:

**config_one.yml**

```
twig:
    globals:
        base_layout: '::layout-one.html.twig'
```

**Then in twig you can just do:**

```
{% extends base_layout %}
```